# Get div from page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've looked everywhere for a technique, but I failed to find much that suited my needs.

Basically, I would like to utilize JavaScript or jQuery (probably using Ajax) to grab a div that contains a word from a page on my site.

I'm not asking anyone to code this for me, I would just like to be pointed in the right direction.

For example, let's say I have this HTML page:

```
<div class='findfromthis'>hello guys</div>
<div class='findfromthis'>goodbye guys</div>
<div class='findfromthis'>goodbye people</div>
```

I would like to display all the `divs` that contain the word "guys" in them.

Thank you so much in advance!!

Comment: @DavidM I just edited my post: I would like to utilize JavaScript or jQuery (probably using Ajax) to grab a div that contains a word from a page on my site.

Comment: Maybe consider using [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) which is included in [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript), like `//div[contains(text(),"guys")]`.

Comment: @DumbProducts: `I've looked everywhere for a technique...` http://api.jquery.com, brilliant documentation and so easy to read full of examples and DEMOS for each functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JQuery has a `contains` selector that will find all elements containing specific text. Something along the lines of `$("div:contains('guys')")` should do the trick. Then you can use .each or .show etc to work with the selected elements.

See http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/ for more detail.

**EDIT :**

The following code was deemed useful by the OP. It'll select all divs with class "findfromthis" which *don't* contain the phrase "guys", and remove them from the DOM:

```
$("div.findfromthis:not(:contains('guys'))").remove();
```

Comment: Yes I was trying that, but using :contains (at least the way I did), make all the divs load on the page, (I did display:none;), and then use contain to display all the divs that contained the term. I don't really like that solution, as all the divs are there, just not all of them are visible. Is this the only solution?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you're trying to achieve? You said that you want to grab divs that contain the word from the page, but you didn't specify what you intend to do with them afterwards. Based on your comment it sounds like you want to start with all the divs on the page, and then remove any that don't contain the word "guys"? You could try the following. It'll remove the divs that don't match from the DOM: $("div.findfromthis:not(:contains('guys'))").remove();

Comment: I'm not sure what ajax has to do with this though as this is purely client-side manipulation of the DOM, using existing elements. It might be more suitable to use ajax to request specific data from the server (e.g. the results including the term "guys"), then only render divs for those results, rather than trying to show and hide divs that are already on the page.

Comment: I can't do it on the server because I need to use the date() function, which is not localized in server languages like PHP. Oh, ad thanks for your code "$("div.findfromthis:not(:contains('guys'))").remove();". It's just what I need.

Comment: :) Also, can you edit your post to also include that "remove" code?

Comment: Yes I saw! thank  you  soooo much! I needed this code so badly. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21737/discussion-between-dumb-products-and-matt-wilson)

Answer (score 0):

Give your div a class, say '.myDiv' and then via jQuery:

```
$('.myDiv').doSomething...
```

I'm not entirely sure how AJAX would play into this, but to point you in the right direction:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Your edit is an entirely different question. But you'd do the same to get the divs. In this case, you'd use 'each':

```
$('.findfromthis').each(function(){
    // for each div you can now grab the text it contains:
    DivText = $(this).text();
    // now you could use a variety of different JS seach techniques to find
    // your content. But one example to search for a word or word fragment would be:
    if (DivText.indexOf("guys") !== -1)){
        // then this div has the word 'guys' in its text somewhere
    }
})
```

If the search term is more complex (like not wanting to find fragments) then you may want to use REGEX for the search part instead.

Again, though, not sure where AJAX would fit into this. This all can happen client-side.